# Cocos2D - removeChild not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In my app I've use the particle designer to produce an animation when bodies collide,
the code is....

```
-(void)collision
{
for (IceCream *iceCream in [iceDict allValues]) {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(iceCream.sprite.boundingBox, player.boundingBox)) {
        if(actualType == 0)
        {
            [self increaseLooseCounts];
            [self updateLives];
        }
        else{
            [self increaseWinCounts];
            [self updateLives];
        }

        //DEFINING THE PARTICLE ANIMATION

        particle = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"part.plist"]; //alt plist working with rainbow.plist
        particle.position = ccp(iceCream.sprite.boundingBox.origin.x,iceCream.sprite.boundingBox.origin.y);
        [self addChild:particle z:2];
        [particle release];

        //CALLING SELECTOR TO END THE PARTICLE ANIMATION
        [self performSelector:@selector(killBlast) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3f];


        int icecreamKey = iceCream.sprite.tag;
        [self removeChild:iceCream.sprite cleanup:YES];
        [iceDict removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:icecreamKey]];

  }
 }
}


-(void)killBlast{
     [particle removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];   
}
```

But as soon as the killBlast is called the app crashes.
Please help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
[particle release];
```

You don't own `particle` object so you don't need to release it. You get it from autoreleased method and then it's retained when becomes added as a child. It will be released once it's removed from parent